# Bash function that assigns a default value to unset variables

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a Bash function that assigns a default value to unset variables. This is a simplified example of my non-working script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# My broken validation function
validate_input() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    set -- "default"
  fi
}

# Parse arguments
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    --foo=*)
    foo="${1#*=}"
    ;;
    --bar=*)
    bar="${1#*=}"
    ;;
    *)
    printf '%s\n' "Invalid argument ($1)"
    exit 1
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

# Validate foo and bar
validate_input "$foo"
validate_input "$bar"

# Print results
printf '%s\n' "foo: $foo"
printf '%s\n' "bar: $bar"
```

So, users can use the arguments `--foo` and `--bar` to set the variables `$foo` and `$bar`. The `validate_input` function checks if a variable is set, and if not it's supposed to assign it the value "default". It's the last bit that isn't working:

```
$ ./test --foo=hello
foo: hello
bar:
```

The expected output is:

```
foo: hello
bar: default
```

I have read up on positional arguments and `set` but I'm a bit out of my comfort zone here.

Comment: Try to send name of variable, not the content: `validate_input "foo"`

Comment: @RomeoNinov - that was what I initially tried. However, in that case "foo" and "bar" are always set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the positional parameters in the function have no affect on the variables, as you've seen. Some alternative implementations:

using [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```bsh
# Validate foo and bar
foo=${foo:-"default"}
bar=${bar:-"default"}
```

using a different parameter substitution with the `:` colon command.

```bsh
# Validate foo and bar
: ${foo:="default"} ${bar:="default"}
```

Using a function that uses a [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) (requires bash version 4.3 or higher)

```bsh
validate_input() {
  local -n var=$1
  [[ -z $var ]] && var=default
}

# Validate foo and bar
validate_input foo
validate_input bar
```

---

Another way to do this is to set the default values *before* parsing the arguments.

```bsh
foo=default
bar=default

# Parse arguments
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
...
done

# Print results
printf 'foo: %s\n' "$foo"
printf 'bar: %s\n' "$bar"
```

Comment: Ah! I had been looking at `foo=${foo:-"default"}` but didn't realise I could use that instead of the function - I tried to use it inside the function. It's working now, and I'm reading up on nameref.